# Crontab -e Doesn't run the script at a given hour

Tags: linux, cron

I have this python3 script found at `/root/Desktop.security/test.py.`
Would like it to run everyday at 10:03, 15:03 and 22:03. Tried all these settings in crontab, but still doesn't run my file. I tried even at reboot

```
# * * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /root/Desktop.security/test.py
@reboot  /usr/bin/python3 /root/Desktop.security/test.py &
03 10,15,22 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /root/Desktop.security/test.py
03 10,15,22 * * * python3 /root/Desktop.security/test.py
```

What I am doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at the [cron tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info), it's full of great debugging information. For your case, have you checked the logging output of the jobs? Is cron running? Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had a typo in the command, the path had a dot in it and also the script has to be run with python3 location of script.py.

The information that you have to give the full path of python executable is obsolete.  ==> therefore the correct answer is `03 10,15,22 * * * python3 /root/Desktop/security/test.py`

Comment: Whether you have to use the full path or not depends on what `PATH` is set to.